# How to move a sprite, change it to a different sprite, then move it again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to keep a sprite in the centre of the screen for a couple of seconds, then move it to the left smoothly till it goes off the screen, then I want a different sprite which should move from the right of the screen to the centre of the screen; all of this in an endless loop.

A very clear example: https://youtu.be/C8FBjEmlJTg?t=19

```
public Sprite Pokemon_0;
public Sprite Pokemon_1;

    void Start()
    {

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_0;

}

    void Update()
    {
    if (transform.position.x >= -80) 

    {
        transform.Translate(-1f,0f,0f);
    }
    else
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_1;         
    }
```

The following is as far as I have got. It moves the sprite to the left smoothly till it goes offscreen and then it changes the sprite to some other sprite.

I am very new so if someone could write a simple script, it would be very helpful. I'm also trying to learn so an explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure at what level I should explain things but would like to help you since you asked a great question and seem willing to learn! Please ask away regarding my code and I'll clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// The [Range()] attribute will make `speed` show up with a slider in the inspector

[Range(0.1f, 5)]
public float speed = 3;
public Sprite[] Pokemons;

private SpriteRenderer sr;
private float worldMiddleX;
private float worldLeftX;
private float worldRightX;
private int currentPokemon = 0;
private float secondsInMiddle = 3f;


void Start()
{
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    sr.sprite = Pokemons[currentPokemon];

    // Find out what X's in the world the left edge, middle & right of the screen is,
    // if you have a 1920x1080 resolution Screen.width will be 1920. But we don't
    // want to position us at x = 1920, because that is FAR away
    // So we need to figure out where in the GAME world, our screen right edge is
    worldMiddleX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, 0f)).x;

    // +100 & -100 because we want it to go outside of the screen a little bit
    // These should be tweaked based on the sprite width
    // Can be done dynamically / programatically too. Their width is in
    // Pokemons[0].rect.width
    worldLeftX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(-100, 0f)).x;
    worldRightX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width + 100, 0f)).x;

    // Start our endlessly looping Coroutine, which will take care of 
    // 1. Moving to the middle.
    // 2. Waiting in middle
    // 3. Moving outside of screen to the left & resetting position
    // 4. Repeat
    StartCoroutine(SlideLeftButWaitMiddleEndlesslyLoop());
}

/*
* Changed from void to IEnumerator to get access to the
* `yield` keyword, which will let us pause execution for X seconds.
* If you do this with a normal method, you will need to invoke it with
* `StartCoroutine()` as it becomes a Coroutine, which will execute in 
* an asynchronous manner
*/
IEnumerator SlideLeftButWaitMiddleEndlesslyLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // yield return *Coroutine* will make sure that the code doesn't continue 
        // its code path until it has completed its Coroutine (method execution)

        // Wait for MoveToMiddle() to finish executing
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveToMiddle());

        // Wait for x seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsInMiddle);

        // Wait for MoveOutsideScreenAndReset() to finish executing
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveOutsideScreenAndReset());
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveToMiddle()
{
    while (transform.position.x > worldMiddleX)
    {
        transform.Translate(-(speed * Time.deltaTime), 0f, 0f);
        yield return null;

        // yield return null here will make this loop pause until next frame
        // so that it doesn't just do all the loops instantly and teleport your sprite
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveOutsideScreenAndReset()
{
    while (transform.position.x > worldLeftX)
    {
        transform.Translate(-(speed * Time.deltaTime), 0f, 0f);
        yield return null;

        // yield return null here will make this loop pause until next frame
        // so that it doesn't just do all the loops instantly and teleport your sprite
    }

    // Change to the next sprite
    nextPokemonSprite();

    // Reset the position, then the Update() method will start again from the top
    // since this method will have fully executed
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = worldRightX;
    transform.position = pos;
}

// If we're at the last Pokemon in the Pokemons array, start over at 0
void nextPokemonSprite()
{
    currentPokemon++;
    if (currentPokemon == Pokemons.Length)
        currentPokemon = 0;

    sr.sprite = Pokemons[currentPokemon];
}
```

I threw it in to a random project of mine, here's how it looks (but I commented out the sprite changing part because my sprites didn't look very good, but it works - I assure you )

[image]

Comment: Btw you can shorten `currentPokemon++; if(currentPokemon == Pokemons.Length){ currentPokemon = 0; } sr.sprite = Pokemons[currentPokemon];` a lot by simply using `sr.sprite = Pokemons[++currentPokemon % Pokemons.Length];` ... and note that actually the plural of Pokemon is Pokemon ^^

Comment: @FredrikSchön Thank you so much, although a lot of this is overwhelming me with words that I'm not familiar with at all such as 'IEnumerator" and the whole logic behind coroutines. I'll learn them in my own time. However, I am getting a lot of "the name "______" does not exist in the current context". It is happening on 'GetComponent', 'StartCoroutine' and 'transform'. Please, can you come up with a solution?

Comment: Sounds like your script file doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`? class `YourClassName : MonoBehaviour`. This is required for attachable scripts on components

Comment: Or could it be that you haven't put the code in a class. I only pasted the inside of the class, since you didn't include it in your original post's code :)

Comment: @FredrikSchön Thanks a ton! It worked and I also learnt a few things along the way!