# Move a cube when the screen is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created an Android game in Unity. The aspect ratio is 9:16. There is a cube in the bottom left of the screen and I am trying to write code so that if the screen is clicked then the cube moves to the bottom middle of the screen, and then on next click to the bottom right.

I searched online but I haven't found anything helpful. Could someone help me out or point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Please enclose what you have tried so far, so we can help you instead of working for you. I also very much recommend you to use `C#` instead of `unityscript`.

Comment: Yes iam using #C now but i already installed for some days i worked only with java and #C is different

Comment: What i am trying is i have a cube and i want to move the cube if screen clicked for the first click it mus to move to middle bottom and second screen click it must to move to right bottom and the next click it must to move to left bottom again and..... i hope you understand me

Comment: I understand you but I don't know what your code looks like. Do you have anything? Code for detecting when a user clicks the screen if nothing else? Just so I have something to work with, so I know how much I need to explain / fill out.

Comment: [Here's a similar answer that I gave to someone with a similar question, it should hopefully answer your question on how to 1. move something and 2. find bottom left, middle & right of the screen in game world)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120463/how-to-move-a-sprite-change-it-to-a-different-sprite-then-move-it-again/57120652#57120652)

Comment: no i actually dont have any code because iam searching in the last to days i dont found any tink about it all the toturials are about move the player to the place that you clicked in that is why i asked here i hope you can help me with something #

Comment: Thank you i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Detecting clicks on screen

```cs
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
         // Someone clicked the screen!
    }
}
```

- [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

---

### Getting bottom middle & bottom right world position from screen position

You will probably need to put some offset on these numbers, since it will be the exact pixel of the edges:

```cs
Vector3 worldBottomMiddle = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, 0f));
Vector3 worldBottomRight = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, 0f));
```

---

### Moving a cube

```cs
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(position);
```

---

### Everything together

```cs
Vector3 worldBottomMiddle;
Vector3 worldBottomRight;

Vector3 target;

bool cubeIsMoving = false;

void Start()
{
    worldBottomMiddle = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, 0f));
    worldBottomRight = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, 0f));
    target = transform.position;
}

void Update() 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
         cubeShouldMove = true;
         if (target == worldBottomMiddle)
             target = worldBottomRight;
         else
             target = worldBottomMiddle;
    }
    if (cubeShouldMove & Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target) < 1)
    {
         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target);
    }

}
```

Something like that should work, but it's not pretty. If you give greater detail on how you wish things to work I can edit the solution to a prettier one.

EDIT: Just saw there was another answer; you should use that code for cycling through positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between screen and world coordinates using [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

```
float distanceFromCamera = 1.0f;
Vector3 bottomCenter = new Vector3(Screen.Width/2, 0, distanceFromCamera);
Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(bottomCenter);

myCube.transform.position = worldPos;
```

You can store your screen-relative locations in an array and cycle between them:

```
Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[] {
    new Vector3(Screen.Width/2f, 0f, 1f),
    new Vector3(Screen.Width, 0f, 1f)
};
int counter = 0;

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseDown(0)) {
        Vector3 pos = positions[Mathf.Min(positions.Length-1, counter++)];
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        myCube.transform.position = worldPos;
    }
}
```